# ros2 controller not loading

Tags: ros2, ros-humble, controller-manager, ros2-control

I'm currently working on a project using ros2_control (Ubuntu 22.04) with the ROS2 Humble distribution. I have created a custom hardware interface with the help of the [ros2_control_demos](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros2_control_demos/tree/humble/example_1) package. However, I'm encountering an issue where the process dies, and I'm having trouble identifying the root cause.

I've included relevant snippets of my controller and launch file below. The error message suggests that the process has died, but I can't pinpoint the exact issue.

controller config:

```
controller_manager:     # node name
  ros__parameters:
    update_rate: 150
    use_sim_time: true

    joint_state_broadcaster:
      type: joint_state_broadcaster/JointStateBroadcaster

    effort_controller:
      type: effort_controllers/JointGroupEffortController


effort_controller:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: true
    joints:
      - JOINT1
      - JOINT2
      - JOINT3
```

controller plugin in urdf file:

```
<ros2_control name="IgnitionSystem"  type="system">
        <hardware>
          <plugin>m4e_mani_control/M4ERos2Controller</plugin>
          <param name="example_param_hw_start_duration_sec">0.0</param>
          <param name="example_param_hw_stop_duration_sec">3.0</param>
          <param name="example_param_hw_slowdown">100.0</param>
        </hardware>
        <joint name="JOINT1">
          <command_interface name="effort">
            <param name="min">-1</param>
            <param name="max">1</param>
          </command_interface>
          <state_interface name="effort"/>
        </joint>
        <joint name="JOINT2">
            <command_interface name="effort">
              <param name="min">-1</param>
              <param name="max">1</param>
            </command_interface>
            <state_interface name="effort"/>
        </joint>
        <joint name="JOINT3">
            <command_interface name="effort">
                <param name="min">-1</param>
                <param name="max">1</param>
            </command_interface>
            <state_interface name="effort"/>
        </joint>
    </ros2_control>
```

launch file:

```
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch_ros.actions import Node
from launch.actions import RegisterEventHandler
from launch.event_handlers import OnProcessExit
from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory

import os
import xacro

def generate_launch_description():

    # package information
    package_description = 'm4e_mani_description'
    urdf_file = 'position_urdf.xacro'
    robot_description_path = os.path.join(get_package_share_directory(package_description),'urdf', urdf_file)    
    
    # controller path
    robot_controllers = os.path.join(get_package_share_directory('m4e_mani_control'),'config','real_m4e_mani_position_control.yaml')
    
    # rviz2 config path
    rviz_config_path = os.path.join(get_package_share_directory('m4e_mani_gazebo'),'rviz','rviz2_config.rviz')

    doc = xacro.parse(open(robot_description_path))
    xacro.process_doc(doc)
    params = {'robot_description': doc.toxml()}
    

    # Robot state publisher
    robot_state_publisher = Node(
        package='robot_state_publisher',
        executable='robot_state_publisher',
        #name = "robot_state_publisher",
        parameters=[params],
        emulate_tty=True,
        output = 'screen'
    )
    
    # joint state publisher to control the joint of robot using its gui
    joint_state_publisher_gui_node = Node(
        package= 'joint_state_publisher_gui',
        executable= 'joint_state_publisher_gui',
        name= 'joint_state_publisher_gui',
        emulate_tty = True,
        output= 'screen'
    )

    # controller manager
    control_node = Node(
        package="controller_manager",
        executable="ros2_control_node",
        name = "controller_manager",
        parameters=[params, robot_controllers],
        output="both",
    )


    # Spawn Joint state broadcaster controller
    joint_state_broadcaster_spawner = Node(
        package="controller_manager",
        executable="spawner",
        arguments=["joint_state_broadcaster",
                   "--controller-manager", "/controller_manager"],
    )

    # Spawn effort controller
    effort_controller_spawner = Node(
        package="controller_manager",
        executable="spawner",
        arguments=["effort_controller", "--controller-manager", "/controller_manager"],
    )

    # rviz node 
    rviz_node = Node(
        package= 'rviz2',
        executable= 'rviz2',
        name= 'rviz2_node',
        output = 'screen',
        parameters=[{'use_sim_time': True}],
        arguments=['-d', rviz_config_path]
    )
    
    ## Launch description
    return LaunchDescription([


        RegisterEventHandler(
        event_handler=OnProcessExit(
            target_action= control_node,
            on_exit=[joint_state_broadcaster_spawner]
        )
    ),

    RegisterEventHandler(
        event_handler=OnProcessExit(
            target_action= control_node,
            on_exit=[effort_controller_spawner]
        )
    ),

    # Nodes
    #control_node,
    robot_state_publisher,
    rviz_node,
    joint_state_publisher_gui_node,

    ])
```

load the plugin dynamically:

```
<library path="m4e_mani_control">
    <class name="m4e_mani_control/M4ERos2Controller"
           type="m4e_mani_control_arm::M4ERos2Controller"
           base_class_type="hardware_interface::SystemInterface">
      <description>
        ros2_control hardware interface
      </description>
    </class>
</library>
```

error:
[image]

without error:
[image]

i have also refereed [this](https://answers.ros.org/question/408856/ros2_control-hardware-interface-startup/) question and i was able to solve this issue but still i cant load my plugin.

```
[ros2_control_node-4] missing state interfaces:
[ros2_control_node-4] ' JOINT1/effort ' ' JOINT3/effort '   
[ros2_control_node-4] missing command interfaces:
[ros2_control_node-4] ' JOINT1/effort ' ' JOINT3/effort '
```

I would greatly appreciate any insights, suggestions, or guidance on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue. If you need additional information, please let me know.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: could you also share the code for your hardware component? The parameters `example_param_hw_start_duration_sec` etc are only for demonstration purposes, I guess you have a different code than that of example_1?

Comment: @ChristophFroehlich, i have the same code from example_1 (the only thing i have replace is HW_IF_EFFORT, instead of HW_IF_POSITION ), once this works then i will adding some additional stuff into this code

Comment: So you have only changed twice the HW_IF_POSISTION, [here](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros2_control_demos/blob/master/example_1/hardware/rrbot.cpp#L124) and [here](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros2_control_demos/blob/master/example_1/hardware/rrbot.cpp#L137)?

Comment: can you try to configure joint2 only (in the ros2_control tag and in the yaml file). I'm wondering why this one should work but the others dont't

Comment: @ChristophFroehlich, Hi, I apologize for the delayed response. I identified an error in the code where I mistakenly used HW_IF_EFFORT instead of HW_IF_POSITION for the state_interface. This resulted in the failure to configure all the joints. I have rectified this issue, and now all the joints are successfully configured.

Comment: However, I am currently facing a new challenge where the controller itself is not loading. I've made adjustments to the launch file to address this issue. Additionally, I have attached a screenshot of my terminal for your reference. Please take a look and let me know if you have any insights or suggestions.

Comment: Please add your solution to the original question as answer to this one and mark it as solved.
Then add a new question with your new problem.